# Write limit of Firestore

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

When committing to firestore, I always encounter these 2 errors:

> 429 This project has exceeded their maximum bandwidth for writes, please retry with exponential backoff. To learn more about limits, see 'Maximum writes per second per database' under 'Usage and limits' section of the support documentation.

or

> 429 This project has exceeded their maximum request_rate/bandwidth/doucment_rate for writes, please retry with exponential backoff. To learn more about limits, see 'Maximum writes per second per database' under 'Usage and limits' section of the support documentation.

Those error messages are too ambiguous, and I've checked the [Usage and limits](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas) but could not find anything useful :<

At the same time, the write speed of Firestore is only 20~30/s:
[image]

So I don't think it's an issue about too many writes...
BTW, I'm using coroutine in Python to commit to Firestore（in order to make the whole process faster） , and there may have some data with the same document name. I'm not sure whether update to same document cause this problem.
Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: I had a similar issue, anything up of 20 TPS on free tier is blocked. If you are on a Paid Plan - Blaze you will not run into these issues as they will askk you to pay.

Comment: Actually we have enabled billing. We can even reach 8k/s. But sometimes it always raises errors, and sometimes it's normal after retrying. It's weird and really painful. @sjmach

Comment: This seems a real strange issue. What is the size of the JSON payload you are trying to insert?

Comment: @sjmach the average size is 300-600kb. Sometimes it will exceed 1Mb, raising an invalid argument error.

Comment: The maximum document size cannot exceed 1 MB as per Firestore documentation - https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#collections_documents_and_fields

Comment: yeah, but in this case it will not raise a 429 error, and this error is more clear that we can handle it easily.